# check which input field has a greater value on keyup

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to output in a list which of the two `input` fields value is higher if both fields have a value in it.

This seems to work except that I also want to compare `0` value. Right now, if I try with `0` and `99`, nothing happens because `.input1` isn't `true`.  Also, is there a better way to do something like this if I have more fields to compare? I don't want to have the browser crash if `keyup` is constantly being checked.

My HTML:

```
<input title="input 1" type="tel" class="input1" value="" maxlength="3" />
<input title="input 2" type="tel" class="input2" value="" maxlength="3" />
<ul></ul>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var input1 = '';
var input2 = '';
var input1Title = '';
var input2Title = '';

$("input").keyup(function () {
    input1 = parseInt($('.input1').val(), 10) || 0;
    input1Title = $('.input1').attr("title");
    input2 = parseInt($('.input2').val(), 10) || 0;
    input2Title = $('.input2').attr("title");

    if (input1 && input2) {
        var description = '';

        if (input1 > input2) {
            description = input1Title + ' is greater than ' + input2Title;
        } else if (input1 < input2) {
            description = input1Title + ' is less than ' + input2Title;
        } else {
            description = input1Title + ' is the same ' + input2Title;
        }

        $("ul").append("<li>" + description + "</li>");
    }
});
```

See my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C5pgc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forcing the values to `0` if the field is empty. Your condition then checks `input1 && input2`, which will fail because in JS `0` equates to `false`. As you are coercing the values to zero anyway, you don't need that condition.

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
    input1 = parseInt($('.input1').val(), 10) || 0;
    input1Title = $('.input1').attr("title");
    input2 = parseInt($('.input2').val(), 10) || 0;
    input2Title = $('.input2').attr("title");

    var result = '';
    if (input1 > input2) {
        result = ' is greater than ';
    } else if (input1 < input2) {
        result = ' is less than ';
    } else {
        result = ' is the same ';
    }
    $("ul").append("<li>" + input1Title + result + input2Title + "</li>");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C5pgc/4/)

Note I also DRY'd up the last part a little.

Comment: Thabks the reason I had the if in there was I only wanted the append to run if both fields were not empty.  Is there a way to do this bu still compare 0

Comment: In that case leave the condition in, but remove the `|| 0` coercion on the field value retrieval.

Comment: Thanks, I had this initially before I posted but it didn't work so I tried to add the || 0.  I have put it in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/55Xhv/ to illustrate what I mean, I only get something added to the list if the number is > 0?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding two extra if's. One asking if input1 is equal to 0 and input2 is more than 0 then the same again vice versa.